# Generate the java messages on FIFO order

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

currently in our one of the project we have JMS services to generate a message when a the pollers detects the files inside a directory. The JMS message is generating randomly. We have used inbound channel adapters for this. We have a requirement to generate the messages on FIFO order (This is based on the time stamp). Is there any possible way to acheive this..? If yes please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the channel adapter a custom `FileListFilter` that sorts the files.

Comment: Hi Gary, I have a confusion between inbound channel adapter and outbound channel adapter. In some of the posts i read that the purpose of the inbound channel adapter is to producing one file per message but in other posts i understood that the inbound and outbound channel adapters are like endpoints to the message channel in which one sends message and other receives message. Please explain the differences and its core purpose. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inbound channel adapters start a message flow; outbound channel adapters end a flow. They are one-way integrations. Inbound and outbound gateways are for request/reply messaging with external systems.